# The confusion of entropy change

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

The entropy is defined as randomness of a substance or a system.
The randomness increases as we go from solids to liquids to gases. Similarly from hard **diamond** to soft **graphite**. Since graphite is soft and slippery, the orderness would be less than diamond.

But acc. to the formula for entropy change during phase transition,
$\Delta S=Q\ \text{(at const. pressure)}/T$
$\Delta S=\Delta H/T\ \text{(at const. pressure)}$

But $\Delta H$ of reaction/process
C graphite --> C diamond is positive
Meaning $\Delta S$ is positive. But it should be negative due to less entropy of diamond.

Where is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure the numbers are right in this [quiz](http://pruffle.mit.edu/3.00/ProblemSets_2001/Sol_P5.pdf) I found, but if you run the numbers on the entropy at different temperatures, the entropy does change sign, i.e. at phase transition temperatures, the entropy of diamond is higher than that of graphite (for some reason).

Comment: Why do you think hardness should be associated with entropy? Graphite actually has an interested crystal structure, its not just amorphous: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite#Structure

Comment: Even if graphite has interesting structure, doesn't it will still be less ordered than diamond. Considering the tight packing of 4 bonded C atoms. I am confused.

Comment: Maybe the standard states are not equilibrium states with one another.  I would think that the corresponding equilibrium states would be at a much higher pressure than the standard state of 1 atm.

Comment: If $\Delta$S had been negative and as $\Delta$H is positive, the reaction wouldn’t occur, as $\Delta$G would be positive.

Comment: Yes, well the reaction will become non spontaneous right?

Comment: The standard free energy of formation of diamond is 2.9 kJ/mol and the standard enthalpy of formation of diamond is 2.0 kJ/mol.  So the standard entropy of formation of diamond (relative to graphite in the standard state is -0.003 kJ/mol.K.  So graphite and diamond are not in equilibrium in the standard state.  The thermodynamics favors graphite.  So, if diamond is present in the standard state, it is converting to graphite.  But the kinetics of the conversion is extremely slow.  This is why $\Delta S$ is not equal to $\Delta H/T$.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The standard free energy of formation of graphite is $0\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$, and the standard free energy of formation of diamond is $2.9\ \mathrm{kJ/mol}$.  So, at $25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ and $1\ \mathrm{bar}$, graphite is favored thermodynamically over diamond.  Let's see what pressure would be required for $\Delta G$ to be zero at $25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$.  Since the temperature is constant, the change in $G$ is described by $\mathrm dG=v\,\mathrm dP$, where $v$ is the molar volume.  The density of graphite is $2.26\ \mathrm{g/cm^3}$ and the density of diamond is $3.51\ \mathrm{g/cm^3}$.  So the molar volumes are $5.31\times 10^{-6}\ \mathrm{m^3/mol}$ for graphite and $3.42\times 10^{-6}\ \mathrm{m^3/mol}$ for diamond.  So, at pressure $P$ (in Pa), the Gibbs free energy for graphite and diamond are:
$$G_\text{Graphite}=0+5.31\times 10^{-6}P$$
$$G_\text{Diamond}=2900+3.42\times 10^{-6}P$$
So, $\Delta G$ at pressure $P$ is $$\Delta G_\mathrm{G\rightarrow D}=2900-1.89\times 10^{-6}P$$So the change in free energy is zero at $P=1.53\times 10^{9}\ \mathrm{Pa}=15\,300\ \mathrm{bar}$

Diamonds are formed naturally at even higher pressures and higher temperatures.  But this is the approximate order of magnitude.

So at $25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$, graphite is highly thermodynamically favored over diamond.  The actual presence of diamonds at $25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ must therefore be a matter of kinetics, rather than thermodynamics.

Comment: 2.9 kJ isn't particularly high value.

Comment: @Mithoron true but takes even *less* to form graphite